# table view does not reload after row selection

Tags: uitableview, swift, cell, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm having issues with searchDisplayController and custom prototype cell. My storyboard has a table view with a custom prototype cell with "Tulona" identifier. Storyboard also has a search display controller. When search bar focused, i want to show some search options as basic cell and after select a option, i want to reload the table with that custom cell. I applied like below code. Everything was perfect except the table view after select a option does not refresh/reload perfectly. When i select a option from display controller's table view, the main table view (storyboard table with "Tulona" cell) does not appear. If i click cancel button from search bar, the main table view did appear with custom cell. Please let me know why main table did not reload after option selection from display controller table view ? I am new in iOS development. My apologies if this is something really obvious or easy and I simply missed it. Please point me in the right direction if so.. Thanks.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {
    var brandCollection : [BrandListItem]?
    var aliaseCollection : [BrandAliaseItem]?
    var brandsToCompare = [Brand]()
    var currentSearchDataArray = [String]()

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

        //var nib = UINib(nibName: "SearchTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        //self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchOptions")

        let dataManager = DataManager.sharedInstance
        self.brandCollection = dataManager.brandCollection
        self.aliaseCollection = dataManager.aliaseCollection     
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func searchDisplayController(controller: UISearchDisplayController, shouldReloadTableForSearchString searchString: String!) -> Bool{
        println(searchString)

        if !searchString.isEmpty{
            //Clearing current search data array for new search key filtering
            self.currentSearchDataArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            //Add all brand matching to new search key from brand collection to the current search data array
            for brand in self.brandCollection! {
                if brand.name.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchString.lowercaseString) != nil {
                    self.currentSearchDataArray.append(brand.name)
                }
            }

            //Add a brand matching to new search key from aliase collection to the current search data array by avoiding duplication
            for aliase in self.aliaseCollection! {
                if aliase.aliaseName.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(searchString.lowercaseString) != nil {
                    var brandName = self.isBrandExist(aliase.brandId)
                    if !brandName.isEmpty{
                        if !contains(self.currentSearchDataArray, brandName){
                            self.currentSearchDataArray.append(brandName)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }


    //Return brand name if brand id and aliase id is same, otherwise empty
    func isBrandExist(id:Int)->String{
        for brand in self.brandCollection! {
            if id == brand.id {
                return brand.name
            }
        }
        return ""
    }


    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            return self.currentSearchDataArray.count
        } else {
            return self.brandsToCompare.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SearchOptions") as UITableViewCell
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        // Check to see whether the normal table or search results table is being displayed and set the Brand object from the appropriate array
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            let brandName = self.currentSearchDataArray[indexPath.row] as NSString
            cell.textLabel?.text = brandName
            //cell.tag = brand.id
        } else {
            let cell: TulonaCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Tulona", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TulonaCell
            var brand = self.brandsToCompare[indexPath.row] as Brand
            cell.setCustomCellForTulona(brand.name, rating: brand.rating, NoOfComment: brand.no_of_comments)
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if tableView == self.searchDisplayController!.searchResultsTableView {
            self.brandsToCompare.append(Brand(id: 100, rating: 5, no_of_comments: "110", name: "Wolf", aliases: []))
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.searchDisplayController!.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }else{
            println("Table view should not reload")
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by adding these lines to didSelectRowAtIndexPath function -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.searchDisplayController!.setActive(false, animated: true)
                println("Table view should reload")
            }
```

Comment: I did solved my issue with those code, but my table view cells always fill up with the same data as data of first index of array self.brandsToCompare. How can i solve this issue ? Please help me out.